# Google Sheet: In a formula, how do I refer to a range within a range?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

| id | name | quantity | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 134 | bags | 256 | in |
| 134 | bags | 1 | in |
| 134 | bags | 344 | out |
| 134 | bags | 12 | in |
| 234 | books | 21 | out |

```
=VLOOKUP(searchKey,filter(C1:D5,A1:A5=134),2,FALSE)
```

In the formula above, I want the `searchKey` to be a relative value based on the result of `filter`. For example, colum1 row4, which is number 344.
So the question is, how do I refer to a range within another range that is generated by a formula function?

Comment: Do you mean the column1 & row**3** of the filtered data? [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) is preferred to `VLOOKUP` in this case. `=INDEX(filter(C1:D5,A1:A5=134),3,1)`

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output